# Is there a norm symbol for $\int (f(x))^{2m+1}dx$?

Tags: functional-analysis

For function $f(x)$, we usually use ($m\in\mathbb{N}$)

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^{2m}\mathrm{d}x=\left[\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^{2m}\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/(2m)}\right]^{2m}=||f||_{L^{2m}}^{2m}$$

Is there a norm symbol for the following? $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^{2m+1}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: It is not a norm.

Comment: I meant: for an odd exponent, you have to put an absolute value around $f$ to play the same game. That is all.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks a lot for the comments.  I obtained analytical results for $W^{(n)}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty [f(x,t)]^{n}\mathrm{d}x,n\in\mathbb{N}$. But I had hard time finding a norm like symbol for odd $n$.  That is why I asked the question. I was not able to find analytical results for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x,t)|^{2n-1}\mathrm{d}x,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval: I have found a work around. $||f(t)||_{L^{2m}}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x,t))^{2m}\mathrm{d}x=W^{(2m)}(t)$. $||f(t)||_{L^{2m+1}}\ge\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x,t))^{2m+1}\mathrm{d}x=W^{(2m+1)}(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

This general type of norm is the $L^p$ norm (which can be specifically stated as an $L^{2m+1}$ norm if you wish, but this is also extensible to real $1<p<\infty$ and $\infty$)
$$||f||_{L^p}^p = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^{p} dx.$$

Your first expression just happens to be a special case since $f^{2m}=|f|^{2m}$ on the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am aware of the definition of $||f||_{L^p}^p = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^{p} dx$. Please see the reason why I ask this question in my comment above.